# PHP snippet won´t work: unset() a commerce checkout pane with custom module

Tags: commerce

This D7 snippet won´t do anything in my code and I don´t know why:

```
<?php
function mymodulename_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter(&$checkout_pane) {
    foreach ($checkout_pane as $pane_name => & $pane_data) {
        if ($pane_name == 'commerce_p2cp_profile') {
            $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
            if ($user->uid > 0) {
                    unset($checkout_pane['commerce_p2cp_profile']);
}}}}
?>
```

I´m trying to hide for registered users a specific drupal commerce checkout pane, created by the [Commerce Profile2 Checkout Pane](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_p2cp) module, and this snippet won´t do anything.

I´ve created a module and enabled it.
After checking the module, I´m pretty sure that th pane is named commerce_p2cp_profile. And at the checkout configuration page the link is named that way, so I think that´s the correct name.

Maybe the problem is with `$user->uid`? Maybe it doesn´t take the current logged in user because `global $user;` is missing? Where should I add thet in that case? Inside the if(), or right after the function name?

Comment: you haven't put in a `global $user;` so your `if` will most likely always fail.  you can put it directly after your initial `function my....` call.

Comment: What @Jimajamma said. Except your `if` (or anything else that depends on `global $user;`) will **always** fail if it's set up the way it is currently. And just to clarify a little, put `global $user;` between the line that says `function mymodulename_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter(&$checkout_pane) {` and the line that says `foreach ($checkout_pane as $pane_name => & $pane_data) {`.

Comment: what @jerdiggity said!

Comment: Thanks for your comments!!! I´ve tried adding `global $user;` and it unsets that pane, but as the fields inside that pane are **mandatory**, it doesn´t let the user finish the checkout process. Maybe because of the `if` error you said? Thanks again!